# Made in USA (or made in IL)

Tags: united-states

I am making a printed circuit board.  The board was designed in Illinois, and it will be manufactured locally by a company also in IL, and it will be assembled (boards cut and components soldered) locally, in IL.  However, the components that are soldered to the board are manufactured throughout the world (i.e., the resistors, capacitors and integrated circuits (ICs)).  Some are manufactured by US companies, and some are even made here in the US, but the majority of the components are manufactured outside of the the US.

I would like to print on the board 'Made in USA' or 'Made in IL, USA' or some variant of that.  But I know that the laws are very strict due to historical abuses.  Since most of the parts are made outside of the US, can I do this legally?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know enough to offer an answer, but *Assembled in IL, USA* may be an option

Comment: I would reach out to a lawyer to check.  I want to say it's enough to get by but there could be a hair split of an argument that you want to make sure.  Ounce of prevention is a pound of cure.

Answer (score 4):

It is unlikely you can call this "Made in USA."  The standard for marking a product as USA is that "all or virtually all" of it be made in the U.S.  This is different for markings for export.

If you are manufacturing something YOU need to learn this stuff.  Dig in to the following website:

https://www.ftc.gov/business-guidance/resources/complying-made-usa-standard

Comment: Thanks for the link.  This is consistent with my impression.  It seems I will not be able to 'make' this in the US.  It's a shame, because that was a priority to me.  The cost difference between having the PCB (the board itself) manufactured in the US and assembled in the US is about a factor of 20 vs having it made and assembled in China.